Creating a KMP library with actual/expect
I've already been experimenting with KMP for a little and I wanted to create a small library that allows user to easily persist/retrieve the theme (light/dark/system).
I've implemented this in an app that I'm doing and I thought it'd be easy to create a library out of it... but nothing further from reality
The backbone of the library would be:
// commonMain
interface ThemePreferences {
    suspend fun saveTheme(appThemeScheme: AppThemeScheme)
    fun observeTheme(): Flow<AppThemeScheme>
}

// androidMain
class ThemePreferenceImpl(private val context: Context) : ThemePreferences {
    private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore(name = THEME_PREFERENCES_NAME)
    override suspend fun saveTheme(appThemeScheme: AppThemeScheme) {
        context.dataStore.edit {
            it[THEME_MODE_KEY] = appThemeScheme.name
        }
    }

    override fun observeTheme() = context.dataStore.data.map { preferences ->
        when (preferences[THEME_MODE_KEY]) {
            AppThemeScheme.LIGHT.name -> AppThemeScheme.LIGHT
            AppThemeScheme.DARK.name -> AppThemeScheme.DARK
            else -> AppThemeScheme.SYSTEM
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val STRING_PREFERENCES_KEY = "app_theme_scheme"
        private val THEME_MODE_KEY = stringPreferencesKey(STRING_PREFERENCES_KEY)
        private const val THEME_PREFERENCES_NAME = "theme_preferences"
    }
}

// iosMain
class ThemePreferencesImpl private constructor() : ThemePreferences {
    private val userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults

    actual override fun getTheme(): AppThemeScheme {
        val themeValue = userDefaults.stringForKey("theme") ?: AppThemeScheme.SYSTEM.name
        return AppThemeScheme.valueOf(themeValue)
    }

    actual override fun saveTheme(theme: AppThemeScheme) {
        userDefaults.setObject(theme.name, "theme")
    }
}

How do I make it a KMP library? I'm having a hard time with playing with expect/actual since I don't think I can make something like:
// commonMain
expect fun createThemePreferences(): ThemePreferences
// androidMain
actual class ThemePreferencesImpl(context: Context)
// iosMain
actual class ThemePreferencesImpl()

How can I deal with these type of situations?

Since it looks like all you are doing is saving some data/preferences why not use the DataStore KMP library? https://developer.android.com/kotlin/multiplatform/datastore

First, same question as the previous comment. Since you're using key/value as the platform-specific portion, why not use existing implementations? There's Datastore as well as Multiplatform Setting (https://github.com/russhwolf/multiplatform-settings), which was one of the first KMP libraries. On expect/actual, I strongly suggest most devs avoid expect/actual classes in most cases. Create an interface in common, impl in platform-specific code. Use expect/actual functions to load the platform's default impl. e/a classes are rigid and it's extremely rare that I use them myself.
